# Hazelcast throwing EventQueue overloaded error in a cluster.

Tags: java, distributed-computing, hazelcast

I am getting the following error in the program.

```
WARNING: [192.168.2.50]:5703 [dev] [3.9-SNAPSHOT] EventQueue overloaded! Failed to process event packet sent from: [192.168.2.50]:5702
```

Mar 28, 2017 12:32:53 PM com.hazelcast.spi.EventService

This is just a sample program that i have written and I have used only a single distributed map which contains around 5 entries. Thus even if there is way to increase the size of the EventQueue, it shouldn't have run out so fast.

What could be the possible reason for such an error. ?

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing into the blue but what do your event listeners do? Event listeners are not supposed to have long running operations as they either block the event queues or event threads. Heavy workload should be offloaded to separate threadpools.